# Sorting Object with Comparator gives Null Pointer

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, comparator

I am trying sort the ArrayList with 3 Card in it.  I am doing this with a Comparator.  (Is this overkill)?  Card.getRank() returns an integer between 2 and 14. I have absolutely no idea where I am going wrong.  I have done this successfully before, and compared with my other code, and it seems the same.  I would greatly appreciate if someone could spread some light on this!

```
public int getHand(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3) {

ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
hand.add(c1);
hand.add(c2);
hand.add(c3);

Collections.sort(hand, new SortCards());
```

---

```
    package com.evorlor.threecardpoker;

    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class SortCards implements Comparator<Card> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Card card1, Card card2) {

        if ((card1.getRank() - card2.getRank()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if ((card1.getRank() - card2.getRank()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;

    }

}
```

---

LOGCAT:

```
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     ... 11 more
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.evorlor.threecardpoker.SortCards.compare(SortCards.java:10)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at com.evorlor.threecardpoker.SortCards.compare(SortCards.java:1)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:320)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:185)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:169)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:2038)
08-06 18:32:56.155: E/AndroidRuntime(4906):     at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1891)
```

---

```
package com.evorlor.threecardpoker;

public class Card {
    private int rank;
    private char suit;

    public Card(int rank, char suit) {
        super();
        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public char getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}
```

Comment: see what is null in comparator

Comment: Can we see the code for `Card`?

Comment: In that case, are you sure that you aren't passing `null` to `getHand`?

Comment: oh wow. this is embarassing. i never instantiated (right word?) the Card

Comment: Either one of your `Card` objects is null, or one of them is returning null from `getRank()`.  I strongly recommend you learn to use the debugger.

Comment: Card was null. sorry for wasting ur time on this one. dont know how i forgot to do that. got ahead of myself

Comment: @Evorlor Kindly ACCEPT the answer if it resolved your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can keep this from happening in the future, is to do a null check. When coding, you want to be sure you handle situations like this. One way might look like:

```
public int getHand(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3) {

    if((c1 != null) && (c2 != null) && (c3 != null)){
        ArrayList<Card> hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
        hand.add(c1);
        hand.add(c2);
        hand.add(c3);

        Collections.sort(hand, new SortCards());
    }else{
        #handle your null card situation here
        System.out.println("One or more card is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

One/More cards passed to `getHand(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3)` are null
You can put assertion check in the first line of `getHand(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3)`
like below

```
Assert.notNull(c1, "Card 1 is null");
Assert.notNull(c2, "Card 2 is null");
Assert.notNull(c3, "Card 3 is null");
```

OR

Execute it in a debugger while having a breakpoint at `getHand(Card c1, Card c2, Card c3)`

Comment: You might want to edit this given the new info; it's pretty clear now that `getRank` isn't the problem

Comment: @DennisMeng Thanks, I have edited and improved my Answer. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Assert isn't a good option. If the assertion isn't true, it will kill the app.

Comment: @Blaine that's why I said, OR validate it in debugger :)

Comment: @JaffarRamay I knew the problem; or at least I asked in an earlier comment whether it was a null `Card`. I just figured I'd make sure you saw the new info before the downvotes start rolling in.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. Good code won't crash when a particular situation is encountered. Using asserts won't fix the problem, it will cause more. Using a debugger isn't really fixing the problem either, it's kind of a given.