# Sorting a nested object with two values using Java 8 Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I am trying to sort a list of students  wherein `student` has instance variables of Address and Language class

```
Class Student {
 Address address;
 Language language;
 //Other fields
  //Setter getters
}

Class Address {

 String streetName;
 //Other fields
 //Setter getters
}

Class Language {
 String name;
 //Other fields
 //Setter getters

}
```

I am trying to sort this list of students by streetName first and then by language and want to keep nulls at the bottom using following code,but getting `NullPointerException`,when Address or Language is Null.

```
list.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing((Student student-> student.getAddress().getStreetName()).thenComparing((Student student) -> student.getLanguage().getName())));
```

Comment: if address is null, student.getAddress().getStreetName() would throw NPE

Comment: Your comparator handles the case that a `Student` is `null`, not that a property value is `null`. Compare with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153431/2711488)

Comment: Thanks @Holger.Can you please suggest how to handle null Address and null language.Still getting NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check for null values. So you can easily handle future situations.
Also reference to this one [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18091867/sorting-object-with-comparator-gives-null-pointer).
No method of Comparator interface does support null values, so be sure to check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change both Address and Language classes to implement Comparable and put the logic of compareTo function to compare by streetName (in case of Address) and by name (in case of Language).

```
    class Language implements Comparable<Language>{
    String name;


        public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Language o) {
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        }
        //Other fields
    //Setter getters

    }

    class Address implements Comparable<Address> {

    String streetName;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Address o) {
            return this.streetName.compareTo(o.streetName);
        }


        //Other fields
    //Setter getters
    }
```

Then change the call to sort as follows:

```
    students.sort(Comparator.comparing((Student student)-> student.address, 
    Comparator.nullsLast(Address::compareTo))
                    .thenComparing((Student student) -> student.language, 
    Comparator.nullsLast(Language::compareTo)));
```

This way, you delegate the comparison of address to Address class and the comparison of language to language class. You force nulls to be at the last by calling comparing.nullsLast with the function compareTo inside Address and Language classes.

----Update -------
Per Holge's comment, you can replace the last code by this:

```
      students.sort(Comparator.comparing((Student student)-> 
      student.address, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
            .thenComparing((Student student) -> student.language, 
      Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```

Comment: When a class implements `Comparable`, you don’t need to create a new comparator like `Type::compareTo`. You can use the existing `Comparator.naturalOrder()`

Comment: @Holger Thank you for the info, first time to know this.